# Change Key Name in All Children [Firebase]

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

Within Firebase I have a structure of data that looks like this

`Parent { 
  child:
    {
      'Article Headline': 'headline',
      'Article Image URL': 'image url',
      'Article Published Date': 'date',
      'Article URL': 'article url',
      'Category': 'mental illness,',
      'Location': 'place',
      'Source Name': 'source'
    }
}`

I would like to change the name of some keys within all the children. For example, I would want to change `Source Name` to `Source` and `Article URL` to `Article` for all children without losing any data. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var data = { 
  child:
    {
      'Article Headline': 'headline',
      'Article Image URL': 'image url',
      'Article Published Date': 'date',
      'Article URL': 'article url',
      'Category': 'mental illness,',
      'Location': 'place',
      'Source Name': 'source'
    }
};

// iterate through the object
for(var item in data) {
    // map new keys to their respective ones
    data[item].child['Source'] = data[item].child['Source Name'];
    data[item].child['Article'] = data[item].child['Article URL'];

    // now delete old keys
    delete data[item].child['Source Name'];
    delete data[item].child['Article URL'];
}

// see for yourself
console.log(data);
```

Comment: this wont work as there is no where showing how it would be updated in Firebase.

Comment: You don't need to update it in Firebase. Just re-parse it as you wish and keep it as it is in the data/firebase.